# Could a 'pulsar-like' planet exist due to the following properties?

Tags: astrophysics, planets, celestial-mechanics, piezoelectric

A [planet](https://phys.org/news/2011-08-planet-diamond-video.html) has been discovered with a composition believed to be made up of diamond. If such a planet were to host a massive satellite of high eccentricity, it seems possible that the large tidal forces induced by the moon on the planet could give rise to a piezoelectric phenomenon in the planet's crystalline structure. This could potentially generate a large magnetic field around the planet in the direction orthogonal to the orientation of the satellite's perihelion, which could, in turn, induce electromagnetic oscillations. The planet would essentially become a crystal oscillator, pulsing an electromagnetic field. Crystalline structures also have large tensile strength. Therefore, it seems possible that such a planet could survive these intense tidal forces and the resulting oscillation deformations. Are there any physical problems with such a theoretical scenario?

Note: Further [research](https://www.space.com/23138-diamond-planet-super-earth-discovery.html) has called into question the possible origin of the discovered planet's diamond composition. Nevertheless, the researchers suggest that, depending on where the planet formed in its system's protoplanetary disk, a diamond composition could be possible.

Comment: This is speculation piled upon speculation. Is there a reference for a planet claimed to be made of crystalline carbon?

Comment: Yes, I have added the reference to the post.

Comment: Fair enough. But a more likely example would be a white dwarf with a planet, since most have cooled and crystallised.